# Client could see another (very old) client's order?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, customer

A client reported that she could see another person's name in the Recently Placed Orders area in her account.

That other persons name is from a very old order...

Why can that be?

Context:

- we upgraded the site from 1.4 to 1.9
- we removed (regretably) all our customers accounts due to a russian
  spam attack, but we plan to rebuild them.

Thanks for any hint.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each order has a customer_id and based on that customer_id old orders are shown to a logged in customer.

If your new customer has the same customer_id as the customer of the old order had, the new customer will see also the orders of the old customer.

When can it happen, that a customer_id is assigned more than once?

- you have resetted the autoincrement of customer_entity after deleting customer data in the database
- you have migrated data to a clean database an started in the customer_entity with a lower increment

Please check the highest customer_id in sales_flat_order and make sure your next increment in customer_entity is higher.

For the conflicting data you can try to check the email addresses in customer and sales tables, if they are different for the same customer_id that might be a hint that you have mixed orders for a customer. Anyway you need to check each conflict because emails can change for the same customer over time.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Between, could this happen with a Guest Client as well? Or only with Registered Customers?

Comment: No, guest clients are not able to see any old orders. Orders from guest clients have the customer_id = 0 in the sales_flat_order table. Btw, changing a customer_id in the order table to 0 transforms an order from a logged in client to a guest order - that might be a way for you to "hide" old orders from beeing seen by new customer ;-)